# iCloud > Manage Storage lists only 'Encrypted File'

Tags: ios, icloud

When creating a document on device 1, then checking the documents on device 2 through iCloud > Storage > Manage Storage > My App, it just lists n number of ‘Encrypted File’ where n is the number of files I expect to see.

On the same device the document was created I see the document as I expect.

Does anyone know why this might happen?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using the shared NSFileManager with `startDownloadingUbiqtuitousItem` is the right approach, not creating a new object and using that, fixes my problem